# How to calculate the Mean absolute error using for loop in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a data matrix denoted by **A** of order **24*1828**, I want to calculate the mean absolute error between each value of the matrix **A** with the last value, for example in first row I want to calculate mean absolute error between each **A[1,1],...,A[1,1827]** to **A[1,1828]** and then find the minimum value of the above vector obtained, similarly I repeat the above process for all **24** rows. Please help how I could this in using  **for loop**.
Regard

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. A smaller matrix than your actual matrix should work just fine for testing.

Comment: mae<- mean(abs(a1-a12))** I want to take each value of the **1st**  row value with the last value of  **1st**  row and calculate the **mea** and the find the minimum value of the vector obtained, similar process is repeated for the row of the matrix **A**.

Comment: I don't understand the *minimum* part. In the 1st row you want to compute the absolute differences between each value and the last one. Then compute the mean of those values. This will give *one* value only, not a vector.

Comment: I want to calculate the absolute deviation as its a single value so their mean will remain the same as the absolute deviation so when we do this with all values in the first, so in this way we obtain a vector of the absolute deviation and in such a vector we calculate the minimum value.  So I want to repeat the same process for all other rows of the matrix  **A**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one-liner with `apply`.

```
# Test data
set.seed(2021)
(A <- matrix(sample(48), ncol = 6))

apply(A, 1, function(x) mean(abs(x[-NCOL(x)] - x[NCOL(x)])))
#[1] 11.6 14.4 24.2 18.8 16.2 17.4 23.0 16.0
```

---

### Edit

After the discussion in comments, here is what I believe is asked.
Function `absdev` computes the absolute differences between the last element of each row and the other elements of that vector. Then function `STAT`, whose default is `min`, is applied to the absolute differences.

```
absdev <- function(x, STAT = min) {
  f <- match.fun(STAT)
  f(abs(x[-NCOL(x)] - x[NCOL(x)]))
}
apply(A, 1, absdev)
#[1]  2  5 10  5  6  3 14  2
```

Comment: Thanks really works, please help how we can do this for the second row of the matrix **A** mean which changes it will require.

Comment: @faheemjan This computes the MAE's for all the rows, that's what `apply` does, it's a `for` loop in disguise. No changes are required.

Comment: thanks for your interest and time, but I am interested in each separately that suppose that for the first row of the matrix  **A** take each value separately and calculate the mean absolute deviation with last value of the first row of the matrix **A**, similarly repeat the process for the remaining rows of the matrix **A**.

Comment: @faheemjan You want to output a vector of absolute differences per row?

Comment: No, I want the absolute deviation of each value with the last value of the same row. so each deviation gives a single value and combined a vector and then I want to calculate minimum value in this vector.

Comment: @faheemjan See if the edit does what you are asking.